How to wrap useSWRMutation and use return data
I'm trying to wrap useSWRMutation and its result in my own hook.
Unfortunately I'm doing something wrong since the data error and isMutating are not getting populated.
This is my current code:
export const useWrappedSWRMutation = (params: useParams) => {
    const { data, error, isMutating, trigger } = useSWRMutation<
        VerifiedEmailResponse,
        AxiosError<TracedError>,
        string,
        useParams
    >('api/endpoint', postWithAxiosFunction)

    const execFunction = useCallback(async () => {
        const result = await trigger(params)
        return result.user_email
    }, [params, trigger])

    const email = data?.user_email

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log({ data, error, isMutating })
    }, [data, error, isMutating])

    return [
        { data: email, isLoading: isMutating, error: error?.response?.data },
        execFunction,
    ] as const
}

The useEffect at the bottom always prints undefined, undefined, false while the call is executed. The call works fine and its results are correct, also if the caller instead of relying on the data, error intercepts directly the function via then and catch it gets the results.
Thank you
